# Sign transaction offline - operation group id

Tags: transactions

How can I sign a transaction offline? Is there any documentation on signing txs offline? I would like to know the operation group id before submitting the tx. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sign a transaction, you must create the forged bytes of that transaction.
Like this:

```
import { TezosToolkit, OpKind } from '@taquito/taquito';
import { InMemorySigner } from '@taquito/signer';
import { RpcClient, ForgeOperationsParams } from '@taquito/rpc';


const tezos = new TezosToolkit('<some RPC URL>');
const rpc = new RpcClient('<some RPC URL>');


const forgeOp = async (senderSK: string, source: string, destination: string, amount: number) => {

    const sourceData = await rpc.getContract(source);
    const counter = (Number(sourceData.counter) + 1).toString();
    const block = await rpc.getBlock()

    // setting the provider before estimating
    tezos.setProvider({ signer: new InMemorySigner(senderSK) });
    const estimations = await tezos.estimate.transfer({ to: destination, amount: amount });

    const opObj: ForgeOperationsParams = {
        "branch": block.hash,
        "contents": [
            {
                "kind": OpKind.TRANSACTION,
                "fee": estimations.suggestedFeeMutez.toString(),
                "gas_limit": estimations.gasLimit.toString(),
                "storage_limit": estimations.storageLimit.toString(),
                "amount": amount.toString(),
                "destination": destination,
                "source": source,
                "counter": counter
            }
        ]
    };

    const forgedBytes = await rpc.forgeOperations(opObj)
    return forgedBytes;
}
```

Now that we have the transaction prepared in the form of a byte string. We can sign it after concatenating `0x03` in the front. The prefix is used (1) to indicate that the representation is hexadecimal (0x), and (2) that it should start with 03, which is a watermark for operations in Tezos.

```
const signOp = async (bytes: string, privateKey: string) => {
    const forgedBytes = "0x03" + bytes;
    const signer = new InMemorySigner(privateKey);
    const signature = await signer.sign(forgedBytes);
    return ({
        "signature": signature.prefixSig,
        "opbytes": signature.sbytes.slice(4)
    });
}
```

The `opbytes` is your signed transaction. It's in the form of forged bytes + signature (without the watermark). Now, you can simply inject it into the blockchain like this:

```
const injectOp = async (opBytes: string) => {
    const opHash = await rpc.injectOperation(opBytes);
    return opHash;
}
```

[Read more here.](https://ocamlpro.com/blog/2018_11_21_an_introduction_to_tezos_rpcs_signing_operations)

Driver code:

```
const main = async () => {
    const txBytes = await forgeOp("<sender's secret key>", '<sender's address>', '<receiver;s address>', <amount>);
    console.log(console.log("Transaction Bytes: ", txBytes));

    const signedOp = await signOp(txBytes, "<sender's secret key>");
    console.log(console.log("Signed Operation: ", signedOp));

    const opHash = await injectOp(signedOp.opbytes);
    console.log(console.log("Operation Hash: ", opHash));
}


main();
```